# Create typedef only when typedef exists in template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to create universal container wrapper.

```
template<typename type>
class ContainerWrapper
{
public:
  using allocator_type = typename type::allocator_type;
  using size_type = typename type::size_type;
  using difference_type = typename type::difference_type;
  using pointer = typename type::pointer;
  using const_pointer = typename type::const_pointer;
  using reference = typename type::reference;
  using const_reference = typename type::const_reference;
  using iterator = typename type::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename type::const_iterator;
  using reverse_iterator = typename type::reverse_iterator;
  using const_reverse_iterator = typename type::const_reverse_iterator;
  using value_type = typename type::value_type;

  iterator begin() noexcept { return container.begin(); }
  const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return container.begin(); }
  iterator end() noexcept { return container.end(); }
  const_iterator end() const noexcept { return container.end(); }
  reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept { return container.rbegin(); }
  const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept { return container.rbegin(); }
  reverse_iterator rend() noexcept { return container.rend(); }
  const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept { return container.rend(); }
  const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return container.cbegin(); }
  const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return container.cend(); }
  const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return container.crbegin(); }
  const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept { return container.crend(); }
protected:
  ContainerWrapper() {}
  type& getContainer() { return container; }
  const type& getContainer() const { return container; }
private:
  type container;
};
```

But not all containers have all kinds of iterators. Is it possible to expose container types only when they exists? Something like

```
using const_reverse_iterator = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<typename type::const_reverse_iterator>::value, typename type::const_reverse_iterator>::type;
```

I could use C++11 only (gcc 4.7). Of course I could create different wrappers for different containers, but I prefer to have one universal wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a base class for each such type, and specialize that base with SFINAE:

```
template <typename...> struct void_type
{
    using type = void;
};

template <typename T, typename = void> struct ContainerWrapper_Base_const_reverse_iterator{};
template <typename T> struct ContainerWrapper_Base_const_reverse_iterator
    <T, typename void_type<typename T::const_reverse_iterator>::type>
{
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename T::const_reverse_iterator;
};

// ... Similar bases for each conditional alias.

template <typename type> class ContainerWrapper
: public ContainerWrapper_Base_const_reverse_iterator<type>
    // ... Inherit from all those bases
{
    // ...
};
```

You could possibly put similar types into a single base, if you're sure that they're always defined together or not defined at all.

Also, you might want to generate those bases with preprocessor, possibly with x-macros.

Also note that the above code could be simplified with C++17 `std::void_t` or a handwritten `template <typename...> using void_t = void;`, but neither work properly in GCC 4.7.

Comment: Also a nice one.

Answer (score 3):

Is a raw array container-y enough for you?
Anyway:

Use SFINAE, overload-resolution and inheritance.

```
namespace detail {
    using std::rbegin;
    template <class T>
    auto reverse_iter_typedefs(long) {
        struct {} r;
        return r;
    }
    template <class T, class X = decltype(rbegin(std::declval<T&>()))>
    auto reverse_iter_typedefs(int) {
        struct {
            using reverse_iterator = decltype(rbegin(std::declval<T&>()));
        } r;
        return r;
    }
}

template <class T>
ContainerWrapper : decltype(detail::reverse_iter_typedefs<T>(1)), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why your aren't using `auto` for you functions?

Using HolyBlackCat's code, you should consider grouping types and functions that will clearly (or should) come together, and using auto to avoid ambiguous function calls:

```
template <typename...> struct void_type { using type = void; };
template<typename type, typename = void>
struct conditional_derive_iterator {
protected:
    conditional_derive_iterator(type*const container) {}
};
template<typename type>
struct conditional_derive_iterator
    <type, typename void_type<typename type::iterator>::type>
{
    // grouping types
    using iterator = typename type::iterator;
    using const_iterator = typename type::const_iterator;
    // this should work with gcc. avoids ambiguity. cleaner code
    inline constexpr auto begin() const noexcept { return c->begin(); }
    inline constexpr auto end() const noexcept { return c->end(); }
protected:
    // this will let you get access to the container
    conditional_derive_iterator(type*const container) : c(container) {}
private:
    type*const c;
};

template<typename type>
class ContainerWrapper :
    public conditional_derive_iterator<type>
{
public:
    // for demo purpose. however, make sure to pass &container to your bases
    ContainerWrapper(const type& c) :
        container(c),
        conditional_derive_iterator(&container) {}
    // continue code...
};

class UselessType{};

void main()
{
    ContainerWrapper<UselessType> a(UselessType{});
    ContainerWrapper<std::vector<int>> b({1,2,3});
    auto itera = a.begin(); // this will not compile
    auto iterb = b.begin(); // this will compile
}
```

While `auto func()...` is c++14 and up, I believe that `auto func() -> return_type` is c++11, so begin/end would look like this:

```
inline constexpr auto begin() const noexcept -> decltype(iterator{}, const_iterator{}) { return c->begin(); }
```

Here is an example: https://repl.it/K9g5/0

You should also take a look at this Member Detector: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

It could come in handy.

Comment: I use auto, but there is old code which not always easy to change, so wrapper should be as close to original containers as possible.

Comment: And auto as function type is c++14 or 17, but not 11

Comment: ISanych, I added c++11 compatibility using auto. Tested on an online gcc compiler (v4.6.3)